# Property is not a Function Exception

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm new to CoffeeScript and I'm running into an issue with the following code block:

```
openShiftVariable = "foo"

class ServerEnvironment
    openShift: "OpenShift"
    cloud9: "Cloud9"
    environmentName: () -> 
        @openShift if openShiftVariable? else @cloud9 #fails
        #"#{@openShift}" if openShiftVariable? else "#{@cloud9}"
    constructor: () ->
        switch @environmentName()
            when @openShift
                console.log "OpenShift"
            when @cloud9
               console.log "Cloud9"

x = new ServerEnvironment()
```

Also at: http://jsfiddle.net/8NVqP/

What I'm trying to do is define a constant for openShift and cloud9 and use that within my switch statement so that I can set up some environment variables.  What I'm finding is that the "environmentName" method appears to not want to return a string and I'm not able to figure out a workaround.

Help appreciated!

EDIT: 11/1/2013

It turns out that Cloud9 runs in OpenShift (doh!) here's a reworked version of the above that works:

```
class ServerEnvironment
   openShift: "OpenShift"
   cloud9: "Cloud9"
   environmentName: () ->
       if process.env.C9_PROJECT? then @cloud9 else @openShift
   constructor: () ->
       console.log "Detecting server environment..."
       @appPath = process.cwd()

       switch @environmentName()
           when @openShift
               console.log "OpenShift detected!"
               @redisURL = "the redis URL"
               @mongoURL = "the mongo URL"
               @nodeJSPort = (Number) process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT
               @nodeJSIP = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP
           when @cloud9
               console.log "Cloud9 detected!"
               @redisURL = "the redis URL"
               @mongoURL = "the mongo URL"
               @nodeJSPort = (Number) process.env.PORT
               @nodeJSIP = process.env.IP

global.ENV = new ServerEnvironment()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
@openShift if openShiftVariable? else @cloud9
```

For:

```
if openShiftVariable? then @openShift else @cloud9
```

Comment: @muistooshort Hum, you are right, somehow I always thought that wasn't possible.

Comment: Also, `if openShiftVariable?` and `if openShiftVariable` have quite  different semantics. Compare http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Bq8Cw/ and http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/fTNzN/

Comment: @muistooshort I guess I shouldn't try to answer questions when I never used the language ;) Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, the goal was to use the existential operator to set up the environment based on whether the variable was defined or not in the process.env variables.